# Regex. Avoid matching string until condition is met?

Tags: javascript, php, regex

Need help with regex.

**String:**
(can contain more levels of "test")

```
[test]
[inner]
    [test]
        [inner]*anything*
        [/inner]
    [/test]
[/inner]
[/test]

[test]
    [inner]*anything*
    [/inner]
[/test]
```

**Should match:**

1.

```
[test]
[inner]
    [test]
        [inner]*anything*
        [/inner]
    [/test]
[/inner]
[/test]
```

2.

```
[test]
    [inner]*anything*
    [/inner]
[/test]
```

**Question:**

How to write regex that matches wanted outcome in PHP?

Here's my example:
https://regex101.com/r/tA2wN8/2

Comment: And the question is?

Comment: Are you expecting an answer in JavaScript or PHP?

Comment: Need this in PHP. Casimir et Hippolyte answer is fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a recursive pattern:

```
~\[test](?:[^[]+|\[(?!/?test])|(?R))*+\[/test]~
```

details:

```
~                     # pattern delimiter
\[test]
(?:                   # non-capturing group (possible content between test tags)
    [^[]+             # all that is not a [
  |
    \[(?!/?test])     # a [ not part of a test tag (opening or closing)
  |
    (?R)              # repeat the whole pattern (recursion)
)*+                   # repeat the group zero or more times (possessive quantifier)
\[/test]
~
```

Note this way is only possible wih PHP or Perl, there is no way for Javascript that doesn't have a recursion feature.